# Is it possible to add a marker to a Google Map without reloading it?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-markers

For instance this URL

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=100,20&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

if I want to change the markers without reloading the page,is that possible, I am using java to display my map ..

Comment: yes its , its usually done with javascript  , you can add , del and move the markers through google maps javascript api http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it on javascript.

```
var markerOptions = {... put your image, variables and google.maps.Map object here };
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
```